# How to favor simplest, most exact field match in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, mongoosastic

Supposed my query is string "X Y", where X and Y are words, and my database contains strings:

```
"A X Y"
"X Y"
"A B C X Y"
"X Y D E"
```

How do I make sure "X Y" is always returned with the highest score? I want to return "X Y" because it matches exactly (no extra words).

After looking at the documentation, I tried using the match_phrase keyword but I believe this only helps match the words in my query in sequence. So match_phrase makes sure "X Y A" is returned but "X A Y" isn't. It doesn't solve the problem of returning the most exact match.

Current implementation (which doesn't work), here I'm trying to return the entry with name="Foo bar" as the top result:

```
GET _search
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "Foo bar"
          }
        }
        ],
        "filter": [],
        "should": [
          {
            "match": {
              "name": {
                "query":"Foo bar",
                "boost": 2
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "match_phrase": {
                "name": {
                  "query": "Foo bar",
                  "boost": 5
                }
            }
          }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized you can achieve the desired behavior using the "term" keyword.

Comment: term query to search "X Y" will not match "X Y A" OR "A X Y"
you can boost your `match_phrase `query results are on top of results.